# Why would you select ATX or SETEXT markdown headers style?

Tags: git, markdown

I'm creating a simple Markdown editor (WYSIWYG style, the user doesn't see the Markdown). What are the consequences in terms of git management when you use Atx or Setext, any recommendation?

Comment: Strange question. ATX and SETEXT were inspiration formats for Markdown but they aren't used with Markdown. Could you elaborate your question?

Comment: Maybe I'm confused with some naming. Initially I want to save what the writer creates using markdown. I'm using turndown a js converter from HTML to Markdown (not sure if its a "something" flavored markdown). One option is to define if headers are :
Setext (dashes under a title name) or ATX (# signs before the title but on the same line)
Github markdown uses ATX I believe, I'm just wondering why you would take one over the other.
https://github.com/domchristie/turndown#options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In term of Git management: very little consequence since it remains a simple text file.

The choice is more about your Markdown engine support ([compared here](https://babelmark.github.io/?text=%23%20Foo%20%23%0A%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%0A%0A%23%23%20Bar%20%23%23%0A---------%0A)) that you will end up using when reading that converted markdown file.

Comment: Thx I was just wondering if there was a conscious decision to have the styling of a header on a different line. Seems like for git management it separates content and style but this is just for headers so I don't think it really is the reason of it.

Comment: @YoannMaingon If there was, it was not Git-related. The creator of markdown mentions those two styles (https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/basics) Atx is generally preferred (https://brettterpstra.com/2015/08/24/write-better-markdown/), including by commonmarks (https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/#atx-headings), which is an unambiguous spec.

Answer (score 4):

The header style choice can have an influence when used in git messages. For example, if you want to automate your message commit generation from your markdown content setext is necessary. Consider your changelog in ATX:

```
# v1.1.1 2020-06-20

## Changed

- foo

## Added

- bar
```

If your release process converts this to an annotated tag, you’ll end up with

```
- foo

- bar
```

In your tag because the headers are seen by git as comments. This won’t be the case with setext.

Though I prefer ATX (as many other do) and would rather advice to handle this in your automation process.

Comment: the question wasn't covering the commit messages, but that makes sense. Thx for the addition.

Comment: I did notice I was a bit off topic but I was looking for anyone having faced this issue. And this was the closest I could find on SO where I was able to share my current issue (which does not seem to be worth a question :) )